# Convert continuous numeric values to discrete categories defined by intervals. code run without error but all categories not created

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis

I have a data frame with a continuous numeric variable, days in Ranges (Days). I want to make a new discrete variable, with few categories based on intervals. **R-Programming**
I create this code its run without any error but in data set values not generated correctly.

## Some example data

```
Raw_data(Days= -362:1081)
```

```
Raw_data<- mutate(Raw_data,Days_Bin = ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 0,Days_Bin <-"0 or early",
ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 5 && Raw_data$ Days >0 ,Days_Bin <- "<=5", 
ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 30 ,Days_Bin <- "<=30",
ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 60, Days_Bin <- "<=60", Days_Bin <- ">60")))))
```

It's run without any error but for the days value it converted in to only two categories of  "0 or early" and "<=30" 
for all 0 or negative values it set "0 or early"
and grater than 0 it set to "<=30"

Also tried this so please don't suggest to do this:

```
Raw_data<- mutate(Raw_data,Days_Bin = ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 0,"0 or early",
ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 5 && Raw_data$ Days >0 ,"<=5", 
ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 30 ,"<=30",
ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 60, "<=60", ">60")))))
```

Comment: Mistake was used && instead of &

.
 Raw_data<- mutate(Raw_data,Days_Bin = ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 0,Days_Bin <-"0 or early",
    ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 5 & Raw_data$ Days >0 ,Days_Bin <- "<=5", 
    ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 30 ,Days_Bin <- "<=30",
    ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 60, Days_Bin <- "<=60", Days_Bin <- ">60")))))
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create reproducible example data

```
  Raw_data <- data.frame(Days =  -362:1081)
```

2.Solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
Raw_data_with_groups <- Raw_data %>%
  mutate(Days_bin = cut(Days,
                        breaks = c(min(Days), 0, 5, 30, 60, max(Days)),
                        labels = c("<=0", "0-5", "5-30", "30-60", ">60")))
```

## Edit:

Or, if you really want to use the `ifelse` construct: Replace `&&` with `&` or even better, leave it out alltogether:

```
    Raw_data <- data.frame(Days=c(-1,0,3,20,31,61))
    df <- mutate(Raw_data,Days_Bin = ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 0,"0 or early",
                                      ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 5,"<=5", 
                                             ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 30 ,"<=30",
                                                    ifelse(Raw_data$Days <= 60, "<=60", ">60")))))
```

Returns:

```
  Days   Days_Bin
1   -1 0 or early
2    0 0 or early
3    3        <=5
4   20       <=30
5   31       <=60
6   61        >60
```